# MySQL - return values based on TOP 5 in different table

Tags: mysql, sql

trying to build dynamic link where TOP 5 from other table will drive the results (below example based on Top 1 to reduce the length of the code). **The main issue is that I can not use LIMIT command.**
I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE work1
(
wo int (5),
duration int (5));

insert into work1 values 
( 1 ,30),
( 2 ,45),
( 3 ,30),
( 4 ,40),
( 5 ,60),
( 6 ,80),
( 7 ,11);
```

and this one

```
CREATE TABLE part1
(
part VARCHAR (5),
wo int (5));

insert into part1 values 
("A" ,1),
('A' ,2),
('A' ,3),
('A' ,4),
('A' ,5),
('B' ,6),
('B' ,7),
('C' ,8),
('C' ,9),
('D' ,10);
```

My results are basically top 1 Count(part) from part1 with wo and duration from work1 table.

In this case part A is at the top with count of 5 and the results I am after is as per below:

```
wo  part    duration
1   A       30
2   A       45
3   A       30
4   A       40
5   A       60
```

Comment: Top 5 suggest using Top not Limit doesn't?

Comment: *"MySQL - return values based on TOP 5 in different table"* *"The main issue is that I can not use LIMIT command."* This question will never be solved as "TOP" results require so kind some kind of limiting clause like `LIMIT`, i have voteclosed this question to be unclear because off this contradiction which makes it unclear.

Comment: The data set isn't very representative, is it, because there are only 5 'A' s :-(

Comment: *"Top 5 suggest using Top not Limit doesn't?"* Well you said it but `TOP` is SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax not MySQL syntax which uses `LIMIT`...

Comment: What does `COUNT` have to do with this? Are you saying if there were six "A'" parts, and no parts with more than six entries, you'd expect six results? If that is the case, what if "A" and "B" both had six entries?

Answer (score 0):

This aims to answer the original question targeting (a "full") MySQL.

---

Aggregate `part1` to get the count per `part` and order by that count descending taking the top 1 using `LIMIT`. Then join the two tables to that derived table.

```
SELECT w1.wo,
       p2.part,
       w1.duration
       FROM (SELECT p1.part
                    FROM part1 p1
                    GROUP BY p1.part
                    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
                    LIMIT 1) x
            INNER JOIN part1 p2
                       ON p2.part = x.part
            INNER JOIN work1 w1
                       ON w1.wo = p2.wo;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5ce45f65ee9688de6ad54d5b0f00e05f)

To changes that from top 1 to top 5 change the `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: I need something without LIMIT (local restrictions).

Comment: @Kalenji: You should have mentioned that in the question and also explain why you cannot use `LIMIT`. Sounds a bit dubious.

Comment: I use SQL hybrid with some commands not available.It is based on mySQL hence it is in the topic.

Comment: @Kalenji: Again you should put that in the question. And remove the [tag:mysql] tag then and choose a more appropriate tag for the system you use then.

Comment: @Kalenji I think I can guess the answer, but to be sure.... does this "hybrid" have any sort of windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  p.wo, p.part, w.duration from part1 p inner join work1 w 
on p.wo=w.wo 
having count(p.*)<6
```